# Repeat an element in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Sorry for the basic question but I can't seem to figure this out. I have the following dataframe:

```
df1
      a              
1     7           
2     26             
3     32            
4     41             
...   
37    7
38    9
```

How would I go about repeating the value at the 37th index, twice such that the following is produced

```
df1
      a              
1     7           
2     26             
3     32            
4     41             
...   
37    7
38    7
39    9
```

I've tried to use loc to no avail:

```
 newp = df1[name].loc[np.repeat(df1.index[-2:].values, 1)] #get the 37th index value to repeat
 listofwty[0].loc[36] = newp
 listofwty[0].index = listofwty.index+1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way, using `pd.concat`, then `sort_index`:

```
pd.concat([df,df.loc[[37]]]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
     a
1    7
2   26
3   32
4   41
...
37   7
38   7
39   9
```

Comment: @codeninja, `pd.concat([df,df.loc[[37]*2]]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: this works! I was trying to use some kind of insert/append function, but could you explain how exactly this line runs?

Comment: @MaxU nice comment.  Thank you.

Comment: You are slicing your dataframe and concatenating that slice back to itself.  An concat takes an array so you can do as many slices as you one in one statement.  Or the same slice using MaxU's method with multiple.

Comment: @ScottBoston Ah I see now, doing it step by step clarifies what exactly is going on. Quite an elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`df.index.insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.insert.html) to insert another entry of 37, and then use [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to duplicate the row:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [7, 26, 32, 41, 7, 9]}, index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 37, 38])
index = df.index
df = df.reindex(index.insert(index.get_loc(37), 37))
print(df)
```

yields

```
     a
1    7
2   26
3   32
4   41
37   7
37   7
38   9
```

Note this create a DataFrame with a non-unique index. To make the index labels
unique, call `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` (as [Scott Boston showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45468307/190597) in his answer).